# Sed capturing too much during substring extraction

Tags: bash, sed, substring, matching

I'm trying to parse a curl response in order to retrieve an img src, identified with the alt tag `captcha`.

So to test my `sed` expression I tried the following:

```
echo 'alt="captcha" src="http://example.com/foo.html" /></p>' | sed -n 's/.*alt="captcha" src="\([^"]*\)/\1/p'
```

However this echos

```
http://example.com/foo.html" /></p>
```

How can I simply return

```
http://example.com/foo.html
```

?

I am new to `sed` so I would like to know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Do you want to use sed then? Add `.*` to the end of the match, you aren't matching the last part of the line so it is unaffected.

Comment: It could be that I'm misunderstanding how sed works of course. Maybe it isn't the right tool for this job.

Comment: It's not the best tool for pulling out strings, but it's fine in this case.

Comment: Great, thanks. If you add that as an answer and explain what I was doing wrong in moderate detail then I'll accept it.

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -o 'http[^"]*'`

Comment: @Cyrus They also want it on the specific line I assume. Maybe `grep -oP 'alt="captcha" src="\K[^"]*'`

Comment: @123: I didn't read these comments until after I'd answered - sorry if I robbed you of the opportunity to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>This answer explains `sed`'s behavior, but [123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923629/123) - who also gave the right answer to the `sed` problem succinctly in a comment - points to a potentially better alternative, *if* you have *GNU* `grep`: `grep -oP 'alt="captcha" src="\K[^"]*'`. GNU `grep`'s `-P` option supports [PCREs](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcresyntax.html), which are more powerful regular expressions than those available in `sed`.</sup>

The issue is not related to *greediness*, but to the fact that your regex only matches *part* of the line:

To **extract a substring in `sed`, your regex  must match the *entire line***.  Otherwise, **any parts *not* matched by your regex are simply *passed through***, as happened with the trailing `" /></p>` in your case; here's a fix:

```
$ echo 'alt="captcha" src="http://example.com/foo.html" /></p>' | 
   sed -n 's/.*alt="captcha" src="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' 
http://example.com/foo.html
```

Note the trailing `.*` I've added, which ensures that the remainder of the line is matched as well.

Without it, what is left of the input line *after* the match is simply appended to the result of your substitution; i.e., the `" /></p>` part. <sup>More correctly: the remaining part of the line is simply not replaced.</sup>

---

Therefore, generally, you'd use an approach such as the following (pseudo notation):

```
sed 's/^...<capture-group>...$/\1/p'
```

Again, the regex must match the *whole line* for this to work.

Due to `sed`'s greedy matching, you neither need `^` nor `$`, though you may choose to add it for clarity of intent.

*Caveat*: If your capture group has no ambiguity, **`.*` is fine to match the *remainder* of the line, but `.*` to match everything *before* the capture group will *not* work in all cases** - see below.

---

A **simple example** to demonstrate the problem:

```
$ sed -n 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)/>>\1<</p' <<<'before"foo"after' # WRONG
>>foo<<"after
```

Note how `\1` does contain the substring of interest captured by `\([^"]*\)`, as intended - the string `foo` between `"..."` - but, because the regex stopped matching just before the closing `"`, the remainder of the line - `"after` - is still output.

Fixed version, with `.*` appended to ensure that the whole line matches:

```
$ sed -n 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/>>\1<</p' <<<'before"foo"after'
>>foo<<
```

Also note how `[^"]*"` is used to match the *beginning* of the line up to the capture group; `.*` would *not* work here, due to `sed`'s greedy matching:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*"\([^"]*\).*/>>\1<</p' <<<'before"foo"after' # WRONG
>>after<<
```

`.*"` greedily matches everything up to the *last* `"`, and so the capture group then captures `after`, which is the run of non-`"` chars. after the *closing* `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use sed grouping. Its always my goto!

**Sed regex:**

```
echo 'alt="captcha" src="http://example.com/foo.html" /></p>' | sed 's/\(^alt.*src=\"\)\(.*\)\(\".*p>\)/\2/g'
```

**Output**

```
http://example.com/foo.html
```

Comment: While your command works, there's no need to introduce additional capture groups - simply appending `.*` to the OP's regex is enough to ensure that only the capture group value is output.